# One spannable string is highlight, another is not

Tags: android, spannablestring

I have two spannable strings and one is highlighting **when clicked** another is not and I can't figure out why.

Spannable thats not highlighting (Result I want):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/activityvideo_chatmodel_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Username: message"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlackFont"/>
```

```
  SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(mMessages.get(position).getPosted_by_user());

        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(@NonNull View view) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, mMessages.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void updateDrawState(@NonNull TextPaint ds) {
                ds.setColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.standardBlue));
                ds.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                ds.setUnderlineText(false);
            }
        };

        spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan, 0, username.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        viewHolder.viewHolderMessage.setText(TextUtils.concat(spannableString, ": ", message));
        viewHolder.viewHolderMessage.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

And I can't figure out why this one is highlighting:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/activity_eventphotos_addedby"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Added by Zsolt 4 hours ago"
    android:textColor="@color/lightGrey"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/activity_eventphotos_view_divider"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/activity_eventphotos_whitechat"/>
```

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(username);


    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
         @Override
          public void onClick(@NonNull View view) {
                 Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Clicked");

         }

          @Override
          public void updateDrawState(@NonNull TextPaint ds) {
           ds.setColor(EventPhotosActivity.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
           ds.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
           ds.setUnderlineText(false);
           }
};

  spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan, 0, username.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
  String date_posted = MethodCalculateTime.calculateAge(serverTime, eventPhotos.get(position).getDate_posted());
  mAddedBy.setText(TextUtils.concat("Added by ", spannableString, " ", date_posted));
  mAddedBy.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Both are using same themes as well

Comment: Is it correct that are both using username.length() when you set the span?

Comment: Yeah. The highlight one is using AndroidX and highlight is not.

Comment: Another common issue is overlapping different clickable surfaces, maybe the elements of the list are clickable?

Comment: I don't have any other onclicklisteners on either. The highlighting one is in a recycler and the other is in a viewpager

Comment: Well, I suggest you to try with a different Span like ForegroundColorSpan to check if it works.